# Is it good to use cache and clone instead of only clone in Image Intervention?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, intervention

I want to make different sizes of an image. Is it good to cache the file and clone it for generating different sizes? Or no different if I use only clone (without cache)?

Without cache:

```
$image->make($this->file);
```

With cache:

```
$image = Image::cache(function($image) {
    $image->make($this->file);
});
```

Generate different sizes:

```
for($sizes as $size) {
    $clonedImage = clone $image;
    // Generate different sizes of that image...
}
```

Comment: You could probably test this for yourself

Comment: I'm not sure what to test. Using microtime to test the performance? Or checking the memory for its usage? How?

Answer (score 1):

Generating different sizes has nothing to do with caching the image.

`Image::cache` will use your the default cache driver of your Laravel project. When you want to retrieve an image using `Image::cache`, it will check if it's available in the cache (hit) or not (miss). When it's available, the operation will be fast and when it's not, it will take some time depending on the business logic that is responsible of building the data to be cached.

You will need to cache every single size you generate in the `for loop` you wrote. I would also suggest using [glide](https://github.com/thephpleague/glide), it will just make your life easier as it handles cache automatically and you can manipulate images on-the-go over HTTP.